# how to align Jbuttons within JPanel within JScrollPane within JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I am trying to encapsulate JTextPane within JButtons, within JPanel, within JScrollPane & within JPanel again, where the entire panel is returned. The following is my code, however it displays buttons horizontally. How and where can I make those buttons fit into the panel? Answer may seem obvious but I still cannot get it right.

```
            JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();  
            JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();

            SimpleAttributeSet attribs = new SimpleAttributeSet();  
            StyleConstants.setAlignment(attribs , StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);  
            tp.setParagraphAttributes(attribs,true);            
            tp.setEditable(false);
            tp.setOpaque(false);
            tp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (100,100));

            JButton jb = new JButton();
            jb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            //jb.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);         

            tp.setText(food_Name);          
            jb.add(tp);

            panel1.add(sp);
            sp.add(panel2);
            panel2.add(jb);
```

Comment: Try changing the layout manager of the `JPanel`s

Comment: Sorry, but i do not get what you mean? may i have an example? my searches have been to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

As has been suggested you need to use a layout manager.

FlowLayout -placed left–to–right then top–to–bottom (***default***)

BorderLayout -five fixed positions, north, south, east, west, centre

BoxLayout - in a single row or column

GridLayout -within cells of a grid with standard sized rows and columns

example code for border layout - check out layout manager on Java API for others

```
public MySupportPanel () { // constructor
    setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("Button 2");
    JButton b3 = new JButton("Button 3");
    JButton b4 = new JButton("Button 4");
    JButton b5 = new JButton("Button 5");

    add(b1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(b2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(b3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(b4, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(b5, BorderLayout.WEST);
  }
```

Comment: thank you.sorry perhaps I did not state what i needed exactly. becoz the number of buttons are determined by DB records, i cannot exactly place those buttons in the layout as suggested. wat i need a is a scrollable JPanel which contains those buttons, which autosizes?

Comment: Ok - I am not quite clear on exactly what you mean but I think think you will need a layout manager. The example I gave is just for buttons, a layout manager can be used for any component objects within your container heirachy.